# CentOS 64 bit Upgrade phpMyAdmin

Tags: centos

It took me forever to install phpmyadmin and all the requirements for it run since I don't really know how to do these kind of stuff. So anyway, I finally got it to work but realized a very old version was installed. Does anyone know easy steps to upgrade to PMA 4.0.6 using Putty.exe? If not then how to remove the old one and reinstall the new one. Because this old version takes forever to edit tables.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to enable `REMI` and `EPEL` RHEL/CentOS/Fedora repository (REMI has recent version of PMA, EPEL provides missing dependencies)

```
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

and then to install the PMA package (current version in repo is 4.0.6)

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install phpmyadmin
```

What HTTP server do you have installed on that machine? With Apache you don’t need to setup any `VirtualHost` because you will get working PMA automatically. The main configuration file for Apache is located under `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf`. The PMA configuration file is in `/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`.

Now, how to remote the old version? Do you install it as RPM package? Then try

```
yum remove phpmyadmin
```

If you installed it by hand, where is it installed? To uninstall it simply means to remove its directory. How do you access it? Are there any aliases to map e.g. `http://www.yourserver.com/phpmyadmin` to that directory? Then, undefine those aliases.

Comment: I'm a beginner here so I didn't understand half of what you just said, sorry for that. The RPM links you gave though, I'm using 64bit, would that work? 

I don't really know what HTTP server this has, I'm just renting a VPS and use putty and filezilla. 

And yes I installed it automatically and not by hand, the old PMA.

Will I lose all my tables after all the steps you just gave?

Comment: Yep, the repo packages contain only repo definitions and the package is platform independent. The later yum install command will take care of selecting right architecture of the package. I overlooked that you are running on CentOS so it should be Apache2 web server. You shouldn't loose any data as PMA is just a management front-end for the MySQL database but if you are not sure by the steps you are going to perform please do the backup before.

Comment: Thank you! Although I'm back with my prob it only shows this as my option 
" phpmyadmin       noarch       2.11.11.3-2.el5.rf             rpmforge       4.2 M" And that version is very old.  I would like PMA 4.0 or at least 3.5.  Btw I'm using centos 5.8 64bit mysql 5.1
"